# Lucene Stemmer packages download

Tags: lucene, porter-stemmer

I want to use these two classes from lucene -

```
 import org.apache.lucene.analysis.snowball.*;
 import org.apache.lucene.analysis.PorterStemmer;
```

But I am not finding these two classes in the lucene 3.5 that I downloaded. Can you tell me from where can I download the jar file having these two classes.

PS - I tried searching for lucene 3.0.1 jar but could not find it.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange, Porter Stemmer should be in the main JAR. However, the snowball analyzers are in the [Lucene analyzers](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.apache.lucene%7Clucene-analyzers%7C3.5.0%7Cjar) jar.